# Все целые числа из диапазона от 1 до 255, представить в виде n^2+m^2, где n,m=>0

Tags: c#

В возрастающем порядке вывести в файл (по 6 чисел в строке) все целые числа из диапазона 1..255, представимые в виде n2+m2, где n,m=>0. 
Даже частичное решение подойдёт, просто я уже не знаю как это даже реализовать, по идее делается при помощи множеств, но как? 
На c# пожалуйста

Comment: Вы с циклами умеете работать? А цикл в цикле сможете сделать? Надеюсь, как возводить во вторую степень не нужно вам объяснять.

Answer (score 1):

Спасобо, всё заработало)

```
        int l = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < 255; k++)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < 255; n++)
            {
                for (int m = 0; m < 255; m++)
                {
                    if (Math.Pow(n, 2) + Math.Pow(m, 2) == k)
                    {
                        l++;
                        if (l < 6)
                        {
                            Console.Write($"{n}^2+{m}^2={k}" + "\t");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"{n}^2+{m}^2={k}" + "\t" ); 
                            l = 0;
                        }                                                       
                        k++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Лучше Write до if вынести, а в if только пустой WriteLine() делать. Нехорошо, когда сложный код два раза повторяется, можно перепутать там что-то внутри.

Comment: Благодарю, за помощь)

Comment: И у вас еще одна ошибка в коде. Попытайтесь найти ее сами. =)

Comment: 256 в циклах а не 255, это имеете ввиду?

Answer (score 0):

В чём ошибка тогда тут?

```
        int x = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
        {                
            for (int j = 0; j < 255; j++)
            {
                if (Math.Pow(i, 2) + Math.Pow(j, 2) == x)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{i}^2 + {j}^2 = {x}");
                    x++;
                }                    
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: `x` тоже в цикл от 1 до 255 оберни.